# Installing Django (or other Python-based) CMS on PaaS Instance?

Tags: web-hosting, cms, django, python, paas

I have a simple hosting instance with gandi.net which is designed to host python programs and comes with a PostgreSQL database configured. I originally had the instance formatted for PHP and used WordPress, which was easy to install and get running. In trying to find instructions for starting a blog using Mezzanine (or Django), all the guides I've read tell me to start a virtual environment on my computer, etc etc and don't ever seem to mention actually putting anything on a server. So my question is this:

How can I, using an SSH shell or Filezilla, install the files needed to get a Python CMS installed on the remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, for install Mezzanine you have to:

1. Login using SSH into your PaaS instance.
2. Run the bash commands listed here in [Mezzanine install guide](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/overview.html#installation)

   > pip install mezzanine

In general, if you have to put files on your provider you can use FTP or SSH over FTP (SFTP) and after that login using SSH to operate like if you're on that machine.